# How to remove this dialog window when submitting the form in Opera browser?

Tags: php, http-headers, opera, mime-types

Using Opera Browser (for 64-bit linux / ubuntu). Why when i click submit it pops up a download option dialog, like shown in the screenshot. I tested it in Chromium/Google Chrome/Firefox/Midori/Arora there it works fine except this Opera? How can i ommit that dialog then?

[image]

```
<form action="/a/userslogin" 
      method="get" 
      id="formusers" 
      name="formuser" 
      target="submitme">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""/>
<iframe id="submitme" name="submitme"></iframe>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP: /a/userslogin

```
  public function usersloginAction() {
    $return = array(
          'flag' => 'test',
          'result' => 'fail'
    );
    $content = Zend_Json::encode($return);
    $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->setBody($content)
            ->sendResponse();
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: Can we see the headers for this page? You tagged jQuery, yet I see no associated code. Could you please provide your code.

Comment: Please see the php code. It works when i remove php code the line ->setHeader....

Comment: You are submitting the form as a regular form and returning a JSON data set in the response. You should have some JavaScript code that submits this form with AJAX and processes the response. If you intend to use a normal form submission, return a normal HTML page or a redirect, not a JSON data set.